# I am getting this error cannot implicitly convert string to system.data.datatable

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, datatable

From combo selected value passing this to the stored procedure and using serialization for generating Bar Chart dashboard. But it's showing me an error

> cannot implicitly convert a string to system.data.datatable

Using DataTable and serialization

Error at this line

```
return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace VOT.DashboardPages
{
    public partial class Velocity : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProjectNo FROM [dbo].[ProjectPlan] ORDER BY ProjectNo asc"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        ddlProjectNo.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        ddlProjectNo.DataTextField = "ProjectNo";
                        ddlProjectNo.DataValueField = "ProjectNo";
                        ddlProjectNo.DataBind();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                ddlProjectNo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select ProjectNo--", "0"));
            }
        }

            public DataTable BindData(String prjNo)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("constr");
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("VelocityByOperationType", connection);
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prjNo", prjNo);
                    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
                    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                          rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    return serializer.Serialize(rows);

               }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }


    protected void ddlProjectNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object Sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = ddlProjectNo.SelectedItem.Value;
        DataTable dt = BindData(ddlProjectNo.SelectedItem.Value);
        //if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: Please read the error carefully. Look at the return type of the `BindData` method, and the return type of the `Serialize` method. There's a discrepancy, isn't there? `serializer.Serialize` returns a `string`, but you have declared that `BindData` returns a `DataTable`. .NET does not know how to convert the returned `string` to the required `DataTable`.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to rewrite this code ? Its very helpful to me

Comment: I can't. You should either return the `DataTable` you read to satisfy your method's signature (`public DataTable ...`), or you should continue to return serialized data and change your signature to match (`public string ...`). Only you know which one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize?view=netframework-4.7.2) method returns a string, not a DataTable.

If you want to return the DataTable from the method then you need to replace the variable returned (line 68) with the following:

```
return dt;
```

This would return the populated DataTable with the DataRows back from the method when it is invoked.

If you want to return the serialised string for DataRows then you need to change your method signature from DataTable to string or create a new method, for example.

```
public string ReturnSerialisedData()
{
    // Add data table code here
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

As an additional note you may want to separate your code into more service/data access layers rather than doing database operations directly in the Page_Load events.